# ¿ Cómo crear Claves compuestas en Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Mi **Modelo City** necesita una **primary key compuesta**, es decir una **primary key** formada por **CityId y CountryId**(del modelo Country).
Cuando quiero crear la Migración, la consola muestra este mensaje:

**The entity type 'City' has multiple properties with the [Key] attribute. Composite primary keys can only be set using 'HasKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

**Modelo Country**

```html
namespace backend_api.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Modelo City**

```html
namespace backend_api.Models
{
    public class City
    {
        [Key]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Key, ForeignKey("Country"), Column(Order = 0)]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        public Country Country { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Aca mi clase **AplicationDbContext.cs**

```html
namespace backend_api
{
    public class AplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {     
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
   
   public AplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<AplicationDbContext>    options): base(options)
   {
   }
}
}
```